# Excel INDEX isn't working with Table reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using Excel from Office 2010.  I am trying to get values from a specific row (or, eventually, rows) in the table, found by running a search.  I can successfully identify the row in the table that I want to output the data from, but the INDEX function is not working when I tell it to go get that row from the database.

```
=INDEX(OutputTable[Department];$F2)
```

is giving me an error, as is:

```
=INDEX(OutputTable;$F2;COLUMN(OutputTable[Department]))
```

Everything I can google tells me that one or the other of these should work, but Excel keeps giving me an error, telling me that the problem is with the first argument of INDEX:  The reference to OutputTable.  I've typed it in manually, and I've navigated to it to select it directly.  $F2 holds the successfully calculated row number from the search.

Why would it tell me that this is erroring?  I can't even figure out where to look.

**EDIT**

```
=INDEX(Output!$A$2:$A$30;$F2)
```

On an impulse, I went ahead and tried using a simple `$A$2:$A$30` reference instead of `OutputTable[Department]`.  It still errors out, telling me that `$A$30` is the problem.  (not the whole reference.  Just that.)  So now I'm even more confused.

Comment: What's the working range of your `OutputTable` and what value is in `$F2`?

Comment: The value in `$F2` comes out as `1`.  (I started by searching for the first item in the list.)  Working range ... = height?  I started with a list that's several thousand tall, then reduced it to about 30.

Comment: No, working range I mean what address does `OutputTable` cover ie `$A$2:$A$30`. Also in your first formula if your `OutputTable` is 2 dimensional this will return an array rather than a single value.

Comment: Are you sure that you should be using a ";" as opposed to a ","? I get an error for that, and it directs me to `$A$30` as you stated.

Comment: Ah.  `A1:E10000`.  And ... it will?  What array would it be returning?  (And why don't the other two work?)

Comment: @Clif - Oh.  (facepalms)  Oh.  Hrm.  Ah.  That's what I get for swapping back and forth between OpenOffice Calc and Excel.  Put that as an answer and I'll approve it.

Comment: Hey we have all been there, hope you have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you should be using a `;` as opposed to a `,`? I get an error for that, and it directs me to `$A$30` as you stated.